# Pandas aggregating groupby object using multiple conditions in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

In my project, I have a dataframe that goes a little something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'posteam': 'NYJ', 'defteam': 'BAL', 'penalty': 1, 'penalty_team': 'NYJ', 'penalty_yards': 10}, 
        {'posteam': 'NYJ', 'defteam': 'BAL', 'penalty': 1, 'penalty_team': 'BAL', 'penalty_yards': 5},
        {'posteam': 'BAL', 'defteam': 'NYJ', 'penalty': 0, 'penalty_team': None, 'penalty_yards': 0},
        {'posteam': 'BAL', 'defteam': 'NYJ', 'penalty': 1, 'penalty_team': 'NYJ', 'penalty_yards': 15}])
```

I would like to aggregate by `posteam` value, but also including `penalty` and `penalty_yards` values where the `penalty_team` value equals the posteam value. The output would be something like

| posteam | penalty | penalty_yards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYJ | 2 | 25 |
| BAL | 1 | 5 |

While the penalty would not have been a penalty by the possessing team, I would like to track total penalties and penalty yards by the team being aggregated.

Currently, my code is

```
df.groupby(['posteam']).agg({
    'penalty': 'sum',
    'penalty_yards': 'sum'
})
```

Which returns the following (where penalties are tracked solely by the possessing team)

| posteam | penalty | penalty_yards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYJ | 2 | 15 |
| BAL | 1 | 15 |

(Keep in mind the difference is `NYJ` is getting one of the `BAL` penalties and `BAL` is getting one of `NYJ`'s)

Is there an easy way to rope in a value given this type of situation? I tried making a helper column to track posteam's penalties, but that excluded values where the team got a penalty while playing as `defteam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that should fix it

```
df1 = df.groupby(['posteam']).agg({
'penalty': 'sum'
})
df2 = df.groupby(['penalty_team']).agg({
'penalty_yards': 'sum'
})
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Clever solution! Definitely a lot simpler than what I was going for, but it does exactly what I want.